# VBA Excel Macro: Offsetting Cell Selection, Selection as Defined by Macro

Tags: vba, excel, selection, offset

I am writing a line of code as part of a more complex program that is not working correctly. I am new to VBA so please bear with me...

Essentially, I am prompting the user to select a cell which is then assigned to the variable 'celNm'.

I then perform the following actions:

```
celNm.EntireRow.Copy
celNm.EntireRow.Insert
```

Next, for reasons specific to the program (and I am assuming the `celNm` will be located at the same cell after the command [Not the same location]), I want to move the cell selection upwards, so it is now located at the row just recently copied above. I am using the following line to do this:

```
celNm.Offset(-1, 0).Select
```

This, however, does not work.

The next step in the program would be to create a list in this location. However the program still creates a list at the previous location (in the cell selected). Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`celNm.Offset(-1,0).Select` only selects the cell above celNm.  It does not change the value of celNm.  To change the value of celNm, you need the following:

```
Set celNm = celNm.Offset(-1,0)
```

I'm assuming celNm is declared as a Range.

Comment: I actually manged to solve the problem just inserting the cell below as opposed to above so the cell address wouldn't change. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to work with `ActiveCell`. Here's an example (You'll want to change "A1" to your celNm variable):

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate
```

[Source](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Using_Loops_in_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/628.html)

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks for the coding specifics but that did not work for more I will paste my code and provide more specifics about what I am doing then you might be better able to help

Comment: I actually manged to solve the problem just inserting the cell below as opposed to above so the cell address wouldn't change. Thanks for the help!